# PC startup memory test

Tags: memory, ram, bios

When a PC starts up it will perform a memory test, is it possible to determine the result of this test or access the test results after boot?

I need to test a systems memory and return the results to a connected module to determine the health of a CPU board, in this case a PC 104 module.

I've been looking at application such as MemTest86+, but this has to be run on bootable media.  It is also way over the top for our requirements.

Comment: You say MemTest86 is way over the top for your requirements, but it's the only way to properly test the memory. The boot-up self-test is exceedingly simple (that is, it does little more than attempting to zero out all the memory).

Comment: @Phylogenesis, the problem is I need to be able to interact with whatever is performing the memory test and return results to a caller.

Comment: The difficulty with that is that the operating system itself is using a not-small portion of the available memory, and it is therefore untestable. Memtest gets around this by running its own very cut down OS that allows it to map itself to different areas of memory as/when required.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, yes, its very thorough and takes quite a while to complete, but for our purposes we just need to know is the CPU good or bad, a quick test to determine this is  all that is required.

Comment: Testing whether a memory module is good or not cannot be a quick process. Many common failures only occur when certain bit patterns are stored/retrieved (like alternating bits) and testing for the various failure modes requires many passes of the memory with different bit patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of this test is "success", otherwise your computer would stop booting. It doesn't really "test" memory, it's more like a discovery that has a chance of detecting faulting modules.

In contrast, memory tests usually check the memory for many common failure patterns. This takes quite a bit longer, and usually means you overwrite the same physical location multiple times, check for parity errors etc. You'll need a specialized tool for that.